# Identtify and filter rows containing conditional formatting in cells

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet containing program participant data. I have used conditional formatting to highlight specific cells that are in need of follow up. How can I either filter or export only ENTIRE ROWS that meet the condition of containing conditional formatting in at least one column of that row?

Comment: You can drop the conditional formatting and use the rule you applied in a helper column. Maybe a column with the header of "Needs Follow Up" and then values could populate as "Y" or "N" instead of some other row being colored. Then you can simply filter your column and manually copy or use `Advanced Filter` to grab desired rows

Comment: Conditional Formatting is strictly a visualization tool. It will not help you with action tasks like this -